# How to stop postgres from showing all rows in a table with thousands of lines

Tags: postgresql

How do I stop Postgres from trying to show all thousands of rows without having to close the cmd window?

I am totally new to Postgresql and I am testing a table with thousands of rows, so when I run SELECT * FROM TableX, I have to keep holding enter until all rows show up. I understand that I can also select only a number of rows with a SQL statement, however, my question is how do I stop Postgres from trying to show all thousands of rows without having to close the cmd window.

Comment: If you just need to check some rows, put a `LIMIT 100` at the end of your query.

Comment: Thank you Michele, I know I can put a limit, but what if I forget and the cmd prompt keeps showing --More--, how do I stop that without having to hit enter until the very last row shows up?

Comment: Oh now I understand, have you tried with `CTRL+C` or simply `q`?

Comment: CTRL + C worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `psql`.

That behaviour is controlled by the pager.

You can disable the pager completely using

```
\pset pager of
```

For more details, please [refer to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)